# How to make a primary alcohol from an alkane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, synthesis, alcohols

Alcohols can be made from alkyl halides, which can be made from alkanes. However $3° > 2° > 1° > 0°$ for alkyl halides synthesis from alkanes. What approach could make an alkane with primary and secondary carbons into only primary alcohols?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'd be on course to win a Nobel prize if you can do that selectively with good yields. This is what the C-H activation chemists are looking at all the time, and it's hard.

Comment: I have suggested a possible mechanism for free radical reaction of alkanes to produce alcohols, give it a read :) https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/72902/alcohols-by-free-radical-substitution

Comment: @PrittBalagopal Seems like an experiment is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Recently a research paper<sup>[[1]](https://doi.org/10.1126/sciadv.abc6688)</sup> has been published which claims to effectively convert *n*-alkanes into *n*-alcohols.

It proposes a quadruple relay catalysis for selective synthesis of *n*-alcohols from *n*-alkanes via the following reaction pathway:

[image: quadruple relay catalysis for selective synthesis of n-alcohols from n-alkanes]

The reaction seems to get yields higher than 75%. The paper itself goes into much detail about each catalyst and its role.

The only catch here is that as this is a hydromethylation, you need to start with an alkane which has one carbon less in its chain than the required alcohol.

---

**Reference:**

[[1]](https://doi.org/10.1126/sciadv.abc6688): Tang, X.; Gan, L.; Zhang, X.; Huang, Z. N-Alkanes to n-Alcohols: Formal Primary C─H Bond Hydroxymethylation via Quadruple Relay Catalysis. *Sci. Adv*. **2020**, 6 (47), eabc6688.